# How to navigate from Shell to other page creating the back button on top page? (Using Prism)

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

In my Shell i have the follow code:

>

```
<ShellContent Title="List"
              Icon="list.png">
      <local:ListPage />
</ShellContent>
```

Using prism without Shell i make this:

>

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(""MyNamespace:///MenuPage/NavigationPage/ListPage");
```

How to do this using Shell?

Comment: I don't use Prism but you can have a look at [Shell Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation) and maybe you can get some idea there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prism does not support Shell at this time. Despite what Microsoft continues to try to tell people, the open source community pretty well is in agreement that Shell is not ready for prime time. This is why you do not yet see support for Shell in major projects, and why we have not yet added support for it.

Comment: Just as I thought. Too bad that Microsoft does not consider a package as important like Prism, fundamental in many projects.

Comment: I don't disagree... keep in mind that we have worked very closely with them to make some efforts to update Shell to make it more capable, but that effort has been put on hold due to .NET MAUI. Ultimately we'll probably see Shell mature to what we need as part of those efforts.